# Currency association with money-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, money-rails

Instead of having a **integer _cents field**, and a **_currency string field**, I've created a **Currency model**, which has:

- iso_code
- usd_rate (the exchange rate to USD)
- name

Examples:

- USD

  - iso_code: **"USD"**
  - usd_rate: **1**
  - name: **"American Dollars"**

Do you know how can I do to integrate this model with the money-rails gem? (I mean, for having a reference to the currency instead of saving the iso_code, and for using the exchange rate in the currency model)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the provided initializer to change the `config.amount_column` and `config.currency_column` options? Changing the `column_name` options in these might let you change it to a method name that returns the your currency model's attributes, and allow the gem to work its magic.

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but after changing the currency column type to integer, it loads USD as the currency. How can I specify that this is a reference to another table? Otherwise it is just a number and it doesn't know which currency the number is